# Parameter Help for Multiple Methods

Tags: java

So I have an assignment to do the following two parameters (there were four in total but the first two were beyond easy)

Parameter 1: `coinToss`

This method simulates tossing a coin and prints out "Head" or "Tail"
For example, when this method is called, it will randomly print out either "Head" or "Tail"

Parameter 2: `dayOfWeek`

Given a number (1-7), this method returns the appropiate day of the week.
For example, Given 1 this method returns "Sunday".

I was actually able to do these two parameters my OWN method and worked perfectly fine. But he recently uploaded how he wanted us to do it and now need help!

How he wants us to do it:

Parameter 3:

```
    m.coinToss();
```

Parameter 4:

```
    System.out.print("Type any number (1-7): ");
    int day = in.nextInt();
    String dayOfWeek = m.dayOfWeek(day);
    System.out.printf("%s is the %d day of the week.\n", dayOfWeek, day);
```

How I did it:

```
public void coinToss (int r) {
    boolean headOrTail = (r % 2 == 0);
    if (headOrTail) {
        System.out.println("Heads");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Tails.");
    }
}

public void dayOfWeek (int whichDay) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Homework2 m = new Homework2();
    if (whichDay == 1) {
        System.out.println("Sunday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 2) {
        System.out.println("Monday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 3) {
        System.out.println("Tuesday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 4) {
        System.out.println("Wednesday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 5) {
        System.out.println("Thursday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 6) {
        System.out.println("Friday.");
    }
    if (whichDay == 7) {
        System.out.println("Saturday.");
    }
    if (whichDay > 7) {
        int day;
        System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1 and 7. ");
        day = in.nextInt();
        m.dayOfWeek(day);       
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int headOrTail = random.nextInt(100) + 1;
    m.coinToss(headOrTail);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Type any number (1-7): ");
    int day = in.nextInt();
    m.dayOfWeek(day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `coinToss` is mostly fine, what you're missing is basically a way to generate a random number. In Java you have the `java.util.Random` class which does just that:

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomInteger = random.nextInt();
```

And now that you have your random integer, I'll leave you to plug that into your coin toss :)

Reference for `Random`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Edit: bonus points: since you only have two possible values, heads and tails, you can use the `nextBoolean()` method and simplify your coin toss condition. Good luck!

Comment: Oh, I had it up earlier in the rest of the coding that deals with parameter one and two. But if you look the teacher wants us to use  

m.coinToss();

I have:

 m.coinToss(headOrTail);

Comment: You're actually almost there, all you need to do is generate your random number (i.e. call `random.nextInt()`) within the `coinToss` method so you don't have to pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can print both dayOfWeek and day.. So You try this one.

You need to change the return type of dayOfWeek method from void to String.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeekDay {
    static WeekDay m = new WeekDay();
    static Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    static Random rand = new Random();
    String day;
    public void coinToss () {
        int headOrTail = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;
        boolean check = (headOrTail % 2 == 0);
        if (check) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Tails.");
        }

        }

        public String dayOfWeek (int whichDay) {


        if (whichDay == 1) {
            day = "Sunday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 2){
            day = "Monday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 3){
            day = "Tuesday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 4){
            day = "Wednesday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 5){
            day = "Thursday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 6){
            day = "Friday.";
        }
        if (whichDay == 7){
            day = "Saturday.";

        }
        if (whichDay > 7) {
            int dayCount;
            System.out.print("Please enter a number from 1 and 7. ");
            dayCount = in.nextInt();
            m.dayOfWeek(dayCount);
        }
        return day;
        }

        public static void main(String[]args){
            m.coinToss();
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.print("Type any number (1-7): ");
            int dayCount = in.nextInt();
            m.dayOfWeek(dayCount);

            String dayOfWeek = m.dayOfWeek(dayCount);
            System.out.printf("%s is the %d day of the week.\n", dayOfWeek, dayCount);
        }

}
```